# C++ add_pointer template with array type

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, type-traits

I would like to use the `std::add_pointer<type>` template from C++ `<type_traits>` header to construct a pointer to an array type.

However, the following generates an error

```
double *y[2];
std::add_pointer<double[2]>::type x;
y = x;  // generates error
```

My MSVC C++ compiler shipped with SDK 7.1 says

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double (*)[2]' to 'double
>   *[2]'
>           There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to
>           arrays

What do I miss here?

EDIT: I want y to be a 2D array with one dimension as 2 and the other variable.
Intended usage is

`y[i][0]`   and `y[i][1]`

Comment: One is an array of pointers, and the other is a pointer to an array. Not the same at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` and `x` don't have the same type here.

As the error message said, `y` is an array with elements of type `double*`. `x` is a pointer pointing to an array with type `double[2]`.

You might change the type of `y` to:

```
double (*y)[2];
std::add_pointer<double[2]>::type x = new double[2][2];
y = x;
// use y[0][0], y[0][1], y[1][0] ...
delete[] y;
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/SBB7335)

Comment: Allright, I got it now :). You are of course right.  It should read double (*y)[2].

Comment: @AndreasH. You could use `y` with `y[0][0]`, `y[0][1]`... See my updated live demo.

Comment: @AndreasH. Glad can help. :)